# Res.buffer is not a function error while fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to use fetch in my create-react-app to get images and import it into my sanity schema. I am trying to fetch the image and use `res.buffer`. But this just directly shows

> TypeError res.buffer is not a function

The code I am using is given below:

```
import React from "react";

const Parser = () => {
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  const filePath =
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/White_Persian_Cat.jpg";
  fetch(filePath).then((res) => res.buffer())
 
  return (
<div></div>
)

};

export default Parser;
```

why could this error be occurring here?

Comment: Is data fetched successfully? You should use try-catch block to catch error along the way

Comment: Yes the data is fetched successfully. Its only the res.buffer part that is givine me error

Comment: "Body has no buffer() method like node-fetch, but instead a arrayBuffer() method for the same function. I checked and it looks like in version 2.0 of node-fetch, arrayBuffer() is implemented for just this exact use case: where we want compatibility on the browser and in nodejs:" I got this from this link: https://github.com/perry-mitchell/webdav-client/issues/74. Try to use arrayBuffer() instead

Comment: @VoQuocThang It worked when i used arrayBuffer() i guess the buffer() method is just not supported outside of nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using arrayBuffer() instead of just buffer().

```
import React from "react";

const Parser = () => {
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  const filePath =
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/White_Persian_Cat.jpg";
  fetch(filePath).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer())
 
  return (
<div></div>
)

};

export default Parser;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such attribute in the `res`. I wonder if this function is only available in nodeJS using the module `node-fetch`. Check the info [here](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/147).

```
//using fetch in browser, res is as follow
{
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/White_Persian_Cat.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Yes.. thats probably it.. In the node fetch docs it said 'This is a node-fetch only API.' But i thought maybe it would work in react app as well.

Comment: @MariumAli After you have ```require('node-fetch')```, can you post the result of ```console.log(res)``` so that we may study tgt